# Increment array to a certain number

Tags: c, arrays

I have an integer array (representing a 4-digit number) that I need to increment so that each integer never goes higher than 3. Basically, it needs to print every 4-digit number that does not have 4 or higher in it. Here's the output I'm expecting compared to the actual output:

```
Expected: 0000 0001 0002 0003 0010 0011 0012 0013 0020 0021 0022 .... 3333
Received: 0000 1000 2000 3000 3100 3200 3300 3310 3320 3330 3331 3332
```

I know my algorithm's messed up but I don't know what to do to it:

```
int i, c[4];

memset(c, 0, sizeof(c));
i = 0;
while (1) {
    testprint(c);
    c[i]++;
    if (c[i] == 3)
        i++;
    if (i == 3)
        break;
}
```

All `testprint` does is display every digit in the array. So how should I change my code to correctly increment the array? And do I even need to use an array? How would I do this without one?

Comment: Your code wouldn't print any `4` 's ... are you sure that is your real output?

Comment: If you want to print every 4 digit number, you're going to need to include some more logic. Currently you cycle the first digit then the second etc., this won't get numbers where the first digit is lower than the second digit for example.

Comment: @M.M sorry about the `4`s, it was from a  previous version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I found the answer with help from @chqrlie:

```
int *ito4(int value, int dest[])
{
    int i = 4;
    while (i-- > 0) {
        dest[i] = value % 4;
        value /= 4;
    }
    return dest;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, arr[4];
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        print_array(ito4(i, buf), 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mind accepting my answer since you copied it?

Comment: @chqrlie I did not copy your answer. Your answer reminded me of something I saw in a C Programming book. I found it in there and modified it to fix my problem

Comment: my bad, the function name and layout looked strikingly similar to my code, but indeed they are different.

Comment: @chqrlie can the OP really accept own answer to own question?

Comment: @WeatherVane ...yes?

Comment: @WeatherVane: it seems possible to accept one's own answer, but one cannot vote it up, and unlike other accepted answers, it does not appear first if another answer has a better score ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function to convert a number into its representation in base 4 (ie: using only digits 0, 1, 2 and 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *itoa4(unsigned value, char *dest, int digits) {
    dest[digits] = '\0';
    while (digits-- > 0) {
        dest[digits] = '0' + value % 4;
        value /= 4;
    }
    return dest;
}

int main(void) {
    char buf[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", itoa4(i, buf, 4));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use an array at all for this purpose. How you choose to represent a value and the value itself are two different things.

The same value, for example 10, can be represented in any different base you wish, it's `10` in base 10, `0xA` in base 16, `12` in base `8` and so on.

At the same time incrementing a value by 1 works under every base. Assuming this you can easily just format an `unsigned integer` to print it as a base4 number.

Mind that with `(value >> (i*2)) & 0x3` you extract the i-th digit, then everything becomes trivial.

Comment: How do I implement this?