# All possible combinations of characters in a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, permutation, shuffle

I've got a string with eight characters in it, e.g. `abcdefgh`. I need to generate all possible 10-character combinations of this string.

For example, all 2-character combinations of this string would be `ab` `bc` `cd` `ef` `gh` `ac` `ad` `ae` `af` `ah`, etc.

I thought of doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40009335/6850771) but I couldn't figure out how to get it working.

What should I do? Is there a simple algorithm I'm missing?

Comment: Combinations of 10 out of 8? Are you sure? No repetitions ("aaaaaaaaba")?

Comment: Use an appropriate length integer to count from 0 to 8^10; for each integer, convert to octal, and use each digit to indicate which of the eight characters to put in that position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 pointers, one on the letter t the start of your string, who is incremented a each time you are on '/0' and the second who is simply incremented on each turn of your loop with a condition fo you don't rewrite an older combination.

```
aa ab ac ... bb bc ...
```

Edit :

No need condition, only the reset of your second pointer have to be 1 on the first pointer